# how to return the actual data when chrome inspector return [object Object] for a jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, console.log

I used `$(this)` in a function like this `$(document).on("dblclick", "td.edit", function(){ makeEditable($(this)); });` to obtain the html element info that is triggered.
But when I do either `console.log` or `alert`, the result will shows only `[object Object]`. 
I wonder is there methods I can use to see what are actually inside? Thank You

After Tibos's suggested methods I get this msg in chrome console:

```
[Object, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: $(document).on("dblclick", "p", function(){ console.log($(this)); });

This code gives me the actual object, which I then can do .text() on if it's the text value you want, or .html() to get the HTML value of the clicked element.

Comment: When you `console.log` you see `[object Object]`? In Chrome?

Comment: @Adam Yes thats what I see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var foo = { bar : 1 };
```

When you do:

```
console.log(foo.toString())
```

It will no longer display the object, but display the string representation of the object, which is [object Object] as with most objects. The same will happen if you cast it implicitly:

```
console.log('This is my object: ' + foo); // This is my object [object Object]
```

To display the object and not its string representation you need to pass the object as a parameter to console.log:

```
console.log(foo); // { bar : 1 }
console.log('This is my object', foo); // This is my object { bar : 1 }
```

In your example if you want to display the jQuery wrapper object aroud the HTML Element that fired the dblclick event, you can do this:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "td.edit", function(){ console.log($(this)); });
```

If you want just the HTML Element, you can do this:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "td.edit", function(){ console.log(this); });
```

Comment: I updated the question, plz elaborate if possible, thank you so much!

Comment: Wonder does the result means the variable is not exist or failed to transfer from one function to another

Comment: Your result is the jQuery wrapper. If you look closely you will find your element under `$(this)[0]` or simply `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$(this).prop('outerHTML');
```

or

```
$(this)[0].outerHTML
```